# Defining Bertin1953 projection in QGIS 3.18.2 Zürich

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

How to define the **Bertin 1953 projection** in QGIS 3.18.2?
I tried to define a custom projection by setting the following:
[image]

This seems to be valid, but when I press the OK-Button, I get this **mysterious error-message**:
[image]

I am using QGIS 3.18.2 on Windows:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The error seems not to be related the Bertin 1953 projection. It seems it is caused by the first projection you defined earlier. Delete the first projection in the list (maybe the second also).

Comment: dont think , that this is the problem , see this screenshot: https://twitter.com/vanuatugis/status/1386725148263215105